# How to generate absolute URL in custom form type?

Tags: php, symfony

I have example custom form type:

```
namespace Acme\SimpleBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ExampleType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->setAction(****-----GENERATE-ROUTE-ABSOLUTE-URL-HERE-----****)
                ->add('email', 'text')
                ->add('send', 'submit');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
         return 'example';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'error_bubbling' => true
        ));
    }

}
```

How can I generate absolute URL (like http://example.com/admin/check_form) to my route?

`$this->generateUrl()` doesn't work, becuse it's not a controller, and `$this->get('router')->generate()` also doesn't work, I don't know why.

Comment: Afaik you can just add the URL as string. Nothing needs to be generated since it is not depending on anything, it is absolute. I assumed with example.com you mean something outside of your project.

Comment: Well, it should be dynamic, according to current domain and directory where app is placed.

Comment: If it has something to do with your project, there must be a route and a controller/action for it. Otherwise the generators will not know where this should point.

Comment: Yes, i have a route called 'check_form', now i want to generate url for this route in setAction() method.

Comment: Third parameter does that: `$this->generateUrl('check_form', array(), true);`

Comment: It gives me UndefinedMethodException, generateUrl() method is not defined, because it's not a controller. $this->get('router')->generate() also throw UndefinedMethodException, this time method get() is not defined.

Answer (score 14):

There are two ways to do it:

- Register your form type as service and inject the router in it: [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)
- Pass your action as option when you create your form in your controller:

  ```
   $form = $this->createForm(new FormType(), null, array('action' => $this->generateUrl('your_route', array(/* your route parameters */), true));
  ```

  Note that you must pass `true` as last argument in order to force the router to generate an absolute url (as you asked for for Symfony < 2.8). If you're using Symfony3, use `UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL` instead of true as suggested by Emilie in the comments.

Comment: As of Symfony 2.8, you must use `UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL` instead of `true` for the referenceType parameter or you'll get a deprecated error

Answer (score 5):

You have to declare your FormType as a service, and with the service container add the router (service id: router), then in your FormType :

```
$this->router->generate('your_route_name', [] /* params */, true /* absolute */);
```

Here the doc : http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html